# Scheduler appointment using dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a simple booking app created using dialog flow, I want to use a calendar in my bot so that the user can select a date for booking,

Something like this :

[image]

Here is a demo I would like to replicate

[Hotel Demo Bot](https://www.messenger.com/t/hotelbotdemo)

Can someone please provide a tutorial on how to achieve something like this in dialog flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve above functionality using [Facebook Webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview)

Inside the page you are rendering in webview you can add calendar and timing UI.
You will be able to get user's current thread details with above field option of calendar on POST or GET request of that form based on your form type.

For more info you can go for [Messenger SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/context)